# save StyleSheet object to css file in Flex3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

i can able to create StyleSheet object , i need to save that StyleSheet object to css file(in the css format).

how can i do in flex3 Air application , is there any build in library ? Or links available to save as *.css file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styleNames` array of the `StyleSheet` class contains the names of all the styles in that object. The `StyleSheet` class also contains a `getStyle` method that returns a style object associated with a given style name. I guess you can make a CSS string using these two. As for saving it as css file, you can do it with the `FileStream` class. Use the `writeUTFBytes` method.

- [StyleSheet](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/text/StyleSheet.html#propertySummary)
- [FileStream](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html)

Comment: so there is no way , i need to manualy loop through array and write to textfile ..
ok thanks Amarghosh for ur reply